# Use user ID on a layout in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm working on a website, and once the user logs in, he is able to check some workouts.

However, I'm trying to pass the user ID from the layout to other pages, as following

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li>
            <a class="page-scroll">Profile</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            @Html.ActionLink("Workouts", "Index", "Routines", new {id = Model.UserID }) 
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="page-scroll">Evaluation</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="page-scroll">Nutrition</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="page-scroll">Services</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="page-scroll">Membership</a>
        </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

And it is not working, I get the following error:

> 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable'
>   does not contain a definition for 'UserID'

However, my Model does have a `UserID` property. I can see it working properly on SQL and even if I takeout the `HTML.ActionLink` from there it works, but when I try to pass that value from the layout it doesn't work.

Any suggestions on how to solve this? I've been reading here and there but no solution so far. 
I may be approaching the problem the wrong way. Is there a way to properly pass the ID of the logged in user to multiple Controllers in order to access the information of that user?

Comment: Why pass the id around?  I would just make a service that grabs the current logged in user and use dependency injection any place you need to get that info.

Comment: Does your code have correct assembly references --- using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore; ( and using System.Linq; -- if using LINQ )

Comment: @Becuzz That's actually a neat solution. Is there a downside to it? I will try to implement it and post back results.

Comment: @LeinadDC I've been using that on a project I've been working on for a couple of months now.  It's worked great so far.

Comment: @Becuzz May I ask how you implemented that? So far I can only get the userID when inside a Controller or if I inherit the Controller class itself because of the Claims.

Comment: @LeinadDC I'll post an answer with the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So rather than pass the userID around, how about making a service to get the logged in user and then grab whatever data you need from your database?  That way you can inject the service wherever you need it.

```
public interface ILoggedInUserService
{
    LoggedInUser GetLoggedInUser();
}
public class LoggedInUserService : ILoggedInUserService
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public LoggedInUserService(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public LoggedInUser GetLoggedInUser()
    {
        string username = GetLoggedInUsername(_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(username))
        {
            return YourServiceToGetUserData.GetUserData(username);
        }
        return null;
    }

    private static string GetLoggedInUsername(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
    {
        return principal?.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value;
    }
}
```

And then in `Startup.cs` where you set up your services for dependency injection add this:

```
services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks a lot.